# Error with left key in command line

Tags: byobu

Accessing through putty with putty-256color in terminal type (and UTF-8 Trasl). I press left or right key in the prompt line. It shows this rectangle:

[image]

But If I press **Ctrl** or **Shift** and **Left/Right** it moves cursor OK.
When I access through VNC it works fine.
I may be something of putty
Byobu 5.87
tmux 1.9

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of `display-panes` tmux command to display the panes id.
Originally, it is bound to `C-b q` but seems like either your right/left keys send this sequence or you have your bindings changed so that that command gets executed on right/left keys.

To check what your keys sequences, use just `cat`.

To check your tmux key bindings use `list-keys` command in tmux.